# PyQt5 iniciar una app varias veces desde diferentes hilos

Tags: hilos, pyqt5

estoy intentando cargar una app en Qt que se ejecuta desde Python, la app solo contiene un QWebView para mostrar una pagina web y esta tiene que poder ejecutarse varias veces y desde hilos distintos (no al mismo tiempo) mi código es este:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView
from threading import Thread


def start():
    app = QApplication([])
    view = QWebView()
    view.show()
    view.load(QUrl('http://www.google.es'))
    app.exec_()
    del app


print '#1'
t = Thread(target=start)
t.start()
t.join()

print '#2'
t = Thread(target=start)
t.start()
t.join()
```

EL caso es que la primera vez se abre correctamente, pero las demás o bien directamente se detiene Python o se abre pero la página no se muestra bien

La aplicación es un plugin para Kodi, y (según parece) cada vez que se ejecuta el plugin lo hace en un hilo.

[image: asd]

Comment: Deberias obtener el siguiente mensaje: WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread, y ese error es valido, Qt te obliga a que solo existe un QApplication y que este se ejecute en el hilo principal por lo que lo que estas intentado es antinatural para Qt y no te lo permitira, esta restriccion es por diseño, no entiendo el motivo de usar hilos, Qt trabaja sobre un event loop que te da la capacidad de ejecutar varias tareas si no son bloqueantes. Lee lo siguiente: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread.

Comment: [cont] Tu tienes un [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), quieres solucionar una posible solucion a tu problema principal, sin estar seguro que esa solucion es correcta, en vez de ello fijate en tu problema principal y pregunta sobre otras alternativa que solucionen ese problema. en conclusion estas yendo por mal camino forzando las cosas

Comment: No puedo hacer que se ejecute en el hilo principal ya que lo que estoy haciendo es un plugin que funciona sobre kodi, y kodi lo ejecuta en otro hilo, yo no tengo control sobre eso, lo único que necesito es que cuando termino y cierro la QApplication esta sea destruida del todo para que cuando cree otra nueva vuelva a empezar de cero, yo no necesito usar hilos, el código que he puesto es para intentar reproducir lo que 'entiendo' que hace kodi

Comment: A eso me referia que tienes un XY problem, te estas fijando en PyQt, y no en kody, te recomiendo mostrar un [mcve] que se refiera a kody, y asi la gente que conozca de kody intentara ayudarte, quizas otra forma de hacerlo